# Std logic vector in VHDL compare with zero and other vector

Tags: vhdl

```
when S3 =>

    NS<=S5;
    Rd_ack<='0';
    if (u=0) then
        send:=u;
        NS<=S4;
    end if;

    if (v=0) then
        send:=u;
        NS<=S4;
    end if;

when S4 =>
```

How can I compare u and v with 0 and u with v ?
I want following statements

```
if( v= u) then. ....
if( u= 0) then
u and v are signa
```

signal u, v: std_logic_vector(0 to 31);

In VHDL can i use send to store the value? send is a variable.
If when we go to state s4 we want to take data in send and assign it to a signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've handicapped someone answering without providing type information for the numerical literal.

If you're serious about testing a std_logic_vector against an integer type you can write an equality operator (`"="`) function that performs the comparison:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity fum is
end entity;

architecture foo of fum is
    signal u,v:     std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
    signal NS,S4:   std_logic;
    function "=" (a:std_logic_vector; b: natural) return BOOLEAN is
        variable as_slv:    std_logic_vector(a'range);
    begin
        as_slv := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(b,as_slv'length));
        for i in a'range loop
            if a(i) /= as_slv(i) then
                return FALSE;
            end if;
        end loop;
        
        return TRUE;
    end function;
begin
SOME_PROCESS:
    process(u,v,S4)
    variable send:  std_logic_vector (u'range);
    begin
        if u = 0  then
            send := u;
            NS <= S4;
        end if;

        if v = 0 then
            send := u;
            NS <= S4;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

This example code analyzes, elaborates and simulates (despite doing nothing interesting).

Notice this one uses natural as the type, std_logic_vector is inherently unsigned, it's a 'bag of bits'.

If you're instead interested in only testing for all '0' values:

```
architecture fee of fum is
    signal u,v:     std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
    signal NS,S4:   std_logic;
    constant ZERO:  std_logic_vector (u'range) := (others => '0');
begin
SOME_PROCESS:
    process(u,v,S4)
    variable send:  std_logic_vector (u'range);
    begin
        if u = ZERO  then
            send := u;
            NS <= S4;
        end if;

        if v = ZERO then
            send := u;
            NS <= S4;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

fum with architecture fee also analyzes, elaborates and simulates while doing nothing interesting.

The constant `ZERO` instead of the equivalent `X"00000000"`, `(others => '0')` not allowed in the expression.

The scope of the variable `send` in this example code is limited to the declarative region, in this case to the process statement `SOME_PROCESS`.  Assuming one were to flesh out the process with a case statement operating off a state value, `send` could be used to assign a signal in that process.

And instead of writing a new operator `"="` function when comparing a numerical literal you could use type conversion:

```
architecture fie of fum is
    signal u,v:     std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
    signal NS,S4:   std_logic;
begin
SOME_PROCESS:
    process(u,v,S4)
    variable send:  std_logic_vector (u'range);
    begin
        if unsigned (u) = 0  then
            send := u;
            NS <= S4;
        end if;

        if unsigned(v) = 0 then
            send := u;
            NS <= S4;
        end if;
        v <= send;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

This has a drawback when simulating:

> #> ghdl -r fum
> ../../../src/ieee/numeric_std-body.v93:1710:7:@0ms:(assertion
> warning): NUMERIC_STD."=": metavalue detected, returning FALSE
> ../../../src/ieee/numeric_std-body.v93:1710:7:@0ms:(assertion
> warning): NUMERIC_STD."=": metavalue detected, returning FALSE
> #>

comparison in the numerical domain (using package numeric_std's "=") is sensitive to metavalues.